# Shortcut for logical operation

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I was just wondering, is there a shortcut for logical operator(`&&`, `||`). Like if I want to do something like `i = i + 10`, I can do `i += 10`

Reason I'm searching this is because I have a validation function which is divided into several functions. Following is a simulation:

```js
function f1(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f2(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f3(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f4(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function validate(){
  var valid = true;
  valid = valid && f1();
  valid = valid && f2();
  valid = valid && f3();
  valid = valid && f4();
  
  console.log(valid);
}

validate();
```

I have tried **&=**

```js
function f1(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f2(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f3(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f4(){
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function validate(){
  var valid = true;
  valid &= f1();
  valid &= f2();
  valid &= f3();
  valid &= f4();
  
  console.log(valid);
}

validate();
```

Now this can works, since `true & false = 0` and `0` is false, but this looks more like a hack and was wondering if there is a better way to do such task?

**Note:**

I have tried `valid = f1() && f2() && f3 && f4();`, but in this approach, if any function returns `false`, subsequent functions are not executed.

#### Edit 1 - Nina's Suggestion

```js
function f1(){
  console.log("f1");
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f2(){
  console.log("f2");
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f3(){
  console.log("f3");
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function f4(){
  console.log("f4");
  return Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) %2 === 0? true:false
}

function validate(){
  var valid = true;
  var validateFuncList = [f1,f2,f3,f4];
  valid = validateFuncList.every(function (f) { return f(); });
  console.log(valid);
}

validate();
```

Now this is a great answer, but this stops if any one returns `false`, which is same as `valid = f1() && f2() && f3 && f4();`

#### Edit 1

Just a minor update. Instead of doing: `valid = valid && func1()` do `valid = func1() && valid`. First approach will not call `func1` if valid is `false`.

Comment: `var valid = f1() && f2() && f3 && f4();`

Comment: Requirement is such that I have to show all validation messages together. I did this at first. But if `f1()` returns false, none of other functions are executed.

Comment: The Mozilla Developer Network lists &=, ^= and |= as valid assignment operators for AND, XOR and OR respectively. There's also %= and **= for remainder assignment and exponentiation assignment.

Comment: You can make all your `f` functions shorter by just removing the `? true:false`

Comment: @Idos That is just for simulation. Actual function have proper business logic to validate fields.

Comment: @JohnClifford If you see, I have already used them. Question is, Is it the right way or just another hack? and if its a hack, is there a better way?

Comment: Should probably point out though Rajesh that &=, ^= and |= are for bitwise operations rather than logical ones, so they equate to x = x & y rather than x = x && y. May not matter for your purposes, but the difference is potentially relevant.

Comment: If bitwise operations are what you're going for, this is the right way. I can't think of a more efficient syntax for the same thing.

Comment: @JohnClifford I have already specified it in question. `true & false = 0` notice only 1 `&`. Also this is the only reason I'm concerned. Yes in my case they work but this is what makes me feel like its a hack and not a proper implementation

Comment: The main reason I pointed out the difference is that you use && in your validate function in the original code, so I wanted to make sure you knew they weren't going to be the same thing. But yes, it's a proper implementation that's supported by pretty much all browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you use an array. It calls all functions.

```
function validate() {
    return [f1(), f2(), f3()].every(Boolean);
}
```

or with an array as parameter

```
function validate(a) {
    return a.every(Boolean);
}

// call
xy = validate([f1(), f2(), f3()]);
```

Comment: Just to conform, if in this `f1` returns false, will it call rest of the functions?

Comment: @Rajesh, no it breaks.

Comment: Yup. Just updated my question regarding it. I want to execute all functions so that all errors are shown together.

Comment: @Rajesh, should it not break?

Comment: No. Basically every function is tied to certain fields. So if user click on submit, this should validate all fields and show all errors at once, instead of showing errors one after other

Comment: I dont know if this is better than `valid = valid && f1()`. This does work, but will be difficult for anyone else to understand the purpose of array here. Still Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Validate them all at once to make it shorter.

```
function validate(){
    var result = f1() && f2() && f3() && f4();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Basically you only check the next `f` function if the previous is true, that's the same that you do in your code, except it doesn't continue if it doesn't need to (if one of the previous is false).

See: [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach which is much more concise. Bitwise-and doesn't short-circuit, so all functions will execute.

```
function validate(){
  var valid = !!(f1() & f2() & f3() & f4());
  console.log(valid);
}
```

Of course `&` is bitwise-and, not logical-and, but as long as your functions return booleans this makes no difference. At the end you can cast to boolean using `!!` if this is important.

Comment: If you notice my second approach, `&=`, it does the same. Yes your solution is more concise, but again, as a bitwise operator, it would yield `0` or `1` and not true or false. So I guess I'd use my approach as real names are bigger and I personally hate line of code that exceeds 80 chars. (*Jusy my POV*). Still thanks.

Comment: @Rajesh Note you can also throw in a `!!` if you want to make sure of printing `true`/`false` (this could work with either `&=` or `&`)

Comment: I know that and I'm using it as well. I just said, my approach is similar to your answer and personally, I'd prefer mine as 5 func with long names in one line will make reading little difficult(*My POV again*).

Comment: Yeah sure, totally up to you, just throwing in some potential ideas for other people who might be in the same situation