# Single JavaScript function to validate input text fields

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to write a single function that can check if an input [text] is empty or not before submitting the data to Php (via Ajax) for processing... This function returns true or false and displays an error message if the input field is empty (handled by another function). The function works as intended, but when have I two fields involved, the if statement breaks. Here's the code:

```
const email = document.getElementById('username');
const password = document.getElementById('password');

if(verifyInput(email) && verifyInput(password)) {
    console.log('Ready');
}
```

So if my email is empty, the next function call, verifyInput(password), never gets executed.

Right now, I've found a workaround by using a multiplication operation:

```
if(verifyInput(email) * verifyInput(password)) {
      console.log('Ready');
}
```

I was wondering if there's a better way to go about this.

Cheers.

Comment: You can take a reference from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149909/shortcut-for-logical-operation

Comment: Also, `*` is a bad hack for this. Instead, do `isEmailValid = ...; isPasswordValid = ...; if(isEmailValid && isPasswordValid)`

Comment: @Rajesh `&&` short-circuits the evaluation

Comment: @KarelFrajták Please check my last comment. I'm creating 2 variables to store validity and using that in condition.

Comment: when your email is empty, the password is not executed because the if will evaluate the second operation only when the first is true (when using &&), if you switch them if(verifyInput(password) && verifyInput(email)) you will the same behaviour but reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
if([email, password].map(verifyInput).every(Boolean)) {
  console.log('Ready');
}
```

First put the values to validate in an array, and then map the `verifyFunction` over them. This produces an array of booleans. Then call `every(Boolean)` to check that they are all true.

Comment: Cool. So I rewrote my verifyInput function to use two parameters (the input element and a string message). The new call looks like so    
  `if([[email, msgStr['error-missing-field']],[password, msgStr['error-password']]].map(verifyInput).every(Boolean)) { console.log("ready"); }`  
  And it works. Cheers man!

Comment: @CodingNoob117 great job! Please consider marking this as the answer. Note that now `verifyInput` still takes a single parameter, the array with the value and the message. This is good because it is easy to be caught out with `map` if your function takes more than one argument. This is because `map` passes the current value as the first parameter, then the index, then the whole array. Consider this: `['1', '2', '3'].map(parseInt)` actually returns `[1, NaN, NaN]`. [Further extensive reading on validation](https://robotlolita.me/articles/2013/a-monad-in-practicality-first-class-failures/)

Answer (score 1):

`&&` logical operator is evaluated from left to right and also "short-circuits" the evaluation. That means when operand is `false` it makes no sense to continue regardless of the remaining operands and the result is `false`.

Use `&` instead: `verifyInput(email) & verifyInput(password)`

Comment: FYI, bitwise operators are considered as bad per AirBnb guidelines. Also, if first is falsey, not sure if this will also execute till end. `0 & 1` is also `0`. Also, better to mention that bit-wise operator returns `0|1` as return value and not `true|false`

Comment: Yo, I just verified this. Using bitwise operators also helped me pull off the validation process. All function calls get executed and if at least one result returns false, we don't move into the if-block. Cheers!